# Detect programmatically when someone is making an access request to a Google Drive element

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-activity-api

I'd like to automatically approve an access request to an item on Drive when it matches some criteria but I cannot find an API that would tell "Mr. X has requested access to document Y".

I know I could check the mailboxes with the GMail API because it creates a special kind of email but that would be too invasive and I have to check the mailboxes of all possible document owners.

I have checked the [Drive Audit Activity API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive) but I can't find something helping.

[image: access request screen]

Any help appreciated !

Comment: So, from what I understand from Reports API, you can check the [Approval requested](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#approval_requested). Isn't this what you need? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: I think that all approval related events refer to the kind of approval workflow you can have in Drive, but not the request to access a document: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9381067?hl=en

Comment: I have been doing some testing with the Reports API, the method I have referenced in the comment above should be what you are looking for. The problem is that I don't see it reported in the Audit Logs, and I have not been able to find more information about it. When sharing a document via `Share>Email` it appears as a `change_user_access` event, but no access requests appear. It also seems unfeasible for 
 the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)... Just a question, do you have a Google domain?

Comment: yes, we do have a Workspace platform if that's what you're asking. I'll check this change_user_access if I can gete it too.

Comment: after few tries on my side too, it seems that no event is triggered when an access request is made, and only an `acl_change` event can be seen when I do validate the access to the file. So I guess I'll just have to set up a watcher on my mailbox and wait for mails from "drive-shares-dm-noreply@google.com"

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#acl_change

Comment: Yes, but this approach only allows monitoring after the request has been completed, and in addition, it must be included in all "watched users". If you think that an "approvals observer" should be implemented in the reporting API, you can go to [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) to add it as a feature request.

Comment: if you want to add a star ;-) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212300347?pli=1

Comment: Hi, did anyone find a solution to this? I read that apparently the Google Drive app for Slack can alert you when someone requests access to a file, so does that mean there is an API somewhere for this event? - https://www.makeuseof.com/things-to-do-integrating-google-drive-slack/